# EF mapping complex type to JSON in DB

Tags: c#, json, database, entity-framework

I am trying to **map a complex type to Json** and **store the info as Json in the DB using EF6 Code First**.

Here's what I have for now:

The complex type

```
namespace EFTests.Data
{
    public class CalibrationMeasureResults
    {
        public CalibrationMeasureResults(int cycle, double input, double 
actualOutputSignal, double nominalOutputSignal)
        {
            Cycle = cycle;
            Input = input;
            ActualOutputSignal = actualOutputSignal;
            NominalOutputSignal = nominalOutputSignal;
            SignalDeviation = actualOutputSignal - nominalOutputSignal;
            SignalDeviationPercent = Math.Abs(SignalDeviation / 16);
        }

        public int Cycle { get; set; }
        public double Input { get; set; }
        public double ActualOutputSignal { get; set; }
        public double NominalOutputSignal { get; set; }
        public double SignalDeviation { get; }
        public double SignalDeviationPercent { get; }
    }
}
```

The entity

```
namespace EFTests.Data.Entities
{
    public class Calibration
    {
        internal string _MeasureResults { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<CalibrationMeasureResults> MeasureResults
        {
            get => _MeasureResults == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalibrationMeasureResults>>(_MeasureResults);
            set => _MeasureResults = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }
}
```

and then via `Fluent-API`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Calibration>()
            .Property(c => c._MeasureResults).HasColumnName("MeasureResults");

modelBuilder.Entity<Calibration>().Ignore(c => c.MeasureResults);
```

Is this a good way of doing it? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: This is not a complex type in EF terminology. What exactly do you see as the complex type here?

Comment: I maybe missunderstand the complex type definition, but afaik `CalibrationMeasureResult` is a complex type. There is no table in the DB for them. I edited my question and posted the MeasureResult class. If I am right it's like 'address' in this example https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx